# Find Values of p for which the integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Find values of *p* for which the integral
$\int_0^1{x^pln(x)dx}$
converges and calculate the value of the integral for these values of *p*.

I got $\int{x^pln(x)dx} = \frac{x^{p+1}ln(x)}{p+1}-\frac{x^{p+1}}{(p+1)^{2}}$  already. Would like to know how to check if it converges.

Comment: Try starting with a substitution.

Comment: Yeah, try a few values for $p$ and check wether $x^{p+1}\ln(x)$ converges as $x\to 0$.

Comment: For the upper value of $x=1$, the answer is clear, for the lower value of $x=0$ you need to consider a limit because you get an indeterminate form in the numerator of the first fraction. One could resort to L'Hospital's Rule, but in order for this limit to exist, there is a constraint on the values of $p$. For example, if $p=-5$, this limit won't exist and then the integral is divergent. But I want your thoughts on this...

Comment: You mean an official answer given by the teacher? Not yet, @UriGoren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts
$$
\int{x^pln(x)dx}=\frac{x^{p+1}\ln{x}-\int{x^{p}dx}}{p+1}=\frac{(x^{1+p} (-1+(1+p) \ln{x}))}{(1+p)^2}
$$
The integral between $0$ and $1$ exists iff
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{(x^{1+p}\ln{x})}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\frac{\ln{x}}{x^{-1-p}}}
$$
converges

If $p<-1$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{(x^{1+p})}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\ln{x}}=-\infty$, then its easy to see why their product cannot be finite.

Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule), it is quite easy to show that if $p>-1$ then the limit converges to $0$

Comment: Did you integrate it right? If yes, would you mind showing me, because I tried to get to the same you did and couldn't.

Comment: Integration by parts $\int u(x) v'(x) \, dx = u(x) v(x) - \int v(x) \, u'(x)  dx $, in our case $u=\ln{x}$ and $v'=x^p$

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows: for $\;p>-1\;$

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{p+1}\left(\log x-\frac1{p+1}\right)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log x-\frac1{p+1}}{\frac1{x^{p+1}}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}=0$$

For $\;p=-1\;$ :

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log x}xdx=\left.\frac12\log^2x\right|_0^1=\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac12\log^2x=-\infty$$

For $\;p<-1\;$ :

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\overbrace{x^{p+1}}^{\rightarrow\infty}\left(\overbrace{\log x}^{\rightarrow-\infty}-\frac1{p+1}\right)=-\infty$$